# recursive function returning a string of moves

Tags: java, string, recursion

Hey everyone I started doing recursion and I have to say its confusing me.
Currently I'm working on the Towers of Hanoi:

```
public static String hanoi(int n, int startPole, int endPole) {
    String ret = new String();
    if (n == 0){
      return ""; 
    }

    int intermediatePole = 6 - startPole - endPole;

    String add3 = hanoi(n-1, startPole, intermediatePole);
    String add = startPole + "->" + endPole + "\n";

    String add2 = hanoi(n-1, intermediatePole,endPole );

    return add + add3 + add2;
}
```

So pretty much what's breaking my brain is -  Who does one return the string of moves such that you get from a call of `hanoi(2, 1, 3)`, you get a output like so, mine only returns one loop of the recursive call

```
1 - 3
1 - 2 
3 - 2 
1 - 3 
2 - 1 
2 - 3
1 - 3
```

Comment: Did you try to print it? When I run your code, I get ```1->3
1->2
2->3``` which seems ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `return add3 + add + add2;`. If your code's output is tried on a physical tower, it doesn't work.
The reason that you are only seeing "one loop of the recurisve call" is that the output show is actually for `hanoi(3,1,3)`, not `2,1,3`.